# How do I calculate I-Bond growth?

Tags: united-states, bonds, retirement

I'm looking into purchasing $10,000 of [Series I Savings Bonds](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ibonds/res_ibonds.htm) every year. I'm trying to understand what the formula is for their growth.

I looked at bond calculators, but to be honest, I'm not very good at this sort of thing, so I couldn't understand it.

I'm 29 right now, so what I'd love to see is something I can plug into Excel where I can list out all years between now and 65 (retirement age), so I can play around with expected yield rates on the bonds overtime. Thanks!

Comment: See [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/154568/109107). Since your example will all ve hypothetical, all you need is round(25*(1+rate/2)^(m/6), 2), where m is the number of months. All you need to change is the rate and how many months ahead you want to go.